# How can I download notebook from Kaggle Using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, kaggle

I want to download all notebook(kernel) for [MNIST dataset in Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/notebooks). I have no knowldege about web-scraping. Can anyone suggest `which python module help me or steps` how can I try? Any types of help will be highly appretiated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Kaggle API](https://www.kaggle.com/docs/api#interacting-with-notebooks) to download public kernels.

`kaggle kernels pull -k [KERNEL] -p /path/to/download -m`

Comment: Thanks for your help. But how i can download all kernel using one command?

Comment: You can get a list of all kernels using `kaggle kernels list`, iterate over each and download using the above command

Comment: How can I `pass all publically available kernel in MNIST list in KERNEL parameter` at once?